# Selenium Test Case does not select first element

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit with an extension of 'SeleniumTestCase' for testing. My problem is that the following  code executes fine:

```
$movies = "//div[@id='sorted_movies_paginator']//li[@class='c-card-list__item']//a[@class='movie-link']";
$this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(2 , $this->getXpathCount($movies));
echo $this->getXpathCount('('.$movies.')[1]')."\n"; // echoes 1
```

while this one returns error:

```
$this->assertElementPresent('('.$movies.')[1]');
```

the error is:

> PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed command:
>   assertElementPresent('(//div[@id='sorted_movies_paginator']//li[@class='c-card-list__item']//a[@class='movie-link'])[1]')
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

and this one also returns error:

```
$this->clickAndWait('('.$movies.')[1]');
```

The error is:

> PHPUnit_Framework_Error :  Invalid response while accessing the
>   Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/':
>   ERROR: Element
>   (//div[@id='sorted_movies_paginator']//li[@class='c-card-list__item']//a[@class='movie-link'])[1]
>   not found

How do you force Selenium Driver to **assert just the first element**?

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate, you'll need to know what element needs the iteration.  In your case, it looks like it is going to be the `<li>`.

You are trying to do (i broke the lines to show visibility):

```
//div[@id='sorted_movies_paginator']
//li[@class='c-card-list__item']
//a[@class='movie-link'][1]
```

What you want, is

```
//div[@id='sorted_movies_paginator']
//li[@class='c-card-list__item'][1]
//a[@class='movie-link']
```

Comment: Thanks, @sircapsalot! Using `//div[@id='sorted_movies_paginator']//li[@class='c-card-list__item'][1]//a[@class='movie-link']` instead of parentheses version worked just fine.

Comment: @nlc2007, if this answered your question, go ahead and click the green checkmark to mark this as accepted so this question can be closed `:)`